# How to set up LSP mode for Emacs with R

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I am struggling to set up [lsp-mode](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/) with Emacs for R. I have installed `languageserver` in R and have [ESS](https://ess.r-project.org/) installed.

When I launch an R script, I get the following message:

```
File mode specification error: (void-function -compose)
```

In my `init.el` I have the following:

```
(use-package lsp-mode
  :init
  (setq lsp-keymap-prefix "C-c l")
  :hook ((ess-r-mode . lsp)
     (lsp-mode . lsp-enable-which-key-integration))
  :commands lsp)
```

I am stumped as to what I'm doing wrong. Googling this problem brought me to [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/uyvlgn/using_lspmode_with_r/) but their solution at the end doesn't help me.

I have been following along [System Crafters' video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E-NAM9U5JYE&list=PLEoMzSkcN8oNvsrtk_iZSb94krGRofFjN&index=1) to try and set up the LSP, but alas to no avail.

I am hoping to set this up with `which-key`,`lsp-ui`, and `company-mode`. So, any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to update the `dash` package. The configuration was fine, but the `dash` package was outdated.